# Converting string to date with timezone

Tags: java, date, timezone, format

I have a string in the pattern yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a
and i can get the time zone object separately in which the above string represents the date.

I want to convert this to the below format.
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z

How can i do this?

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/  makes all date manipulations in java much much easier

Comment: @Emil i got to know this feature after you said :), Thanks.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 26):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and explicitly set the [TimeZone](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html):

```
public static Date getSomeDate(final String str, final TimeZone tz)
    throws ParseException {
  final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a");
  sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
  return sdf.parse(str);
}

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws InterruptedException
 * @throws ParseException
 */
public static void main(final String[] args) throws ParseException {
  final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
  System.out.println(sdf.format(getSomeDate(
      "2010-11-17 01:12 pm", TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"))));
  System.out.println(sdf.format(getSomeDate(
      "2010-11-17 01:12 pm", TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"))));
}
```

Prints out:

> 2010-11-17 13:12:00 +0100
>
> 2010-11-17 20:12:00 +0100

**Update 2010-12-01:**
If you want to explicitly printout a special TimeZone, set it in the SimpleDateFormat:

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone .getTimeZone("IST")); 
System.out.println(sdf.format(getSomeDate(
    "2010-11-17 01:12 pm", TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"))));
```

Which prints `2010-11-17 13:12:00 +0530`

Comment: Thanks Mr.Michael, The date & time gets changed according to the Timezone.Note down the +100, it doesn't changes the TIMEZONE offset

Comment: @shal: Sorry, I do not understand your second sentence. Do you think something is wrong?

Comment: @ Michael, I am saying the time is getting converted properly but see the "Z" part in the date values printed "+0100" it doesn't changes.For eg if i am converting a date from GMT to IST then the "Z" part of the converted date must be "+0530".

Comment: This depends on the system the code is running. For `IST` it prints out `2010-11-17 07:42:00 +0000` on ideone.

Comment: @shal: Distinguish between the generation of a valid date with an explicit TimeZone set when parsing and the printout of the date with a explicit TimeZone.

Comment: FYI, the old [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) classes are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system). Supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime`, `ZoneId`, `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See [the answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41796443/5772882).

Answer (score 15):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse(                        // Parse string as value without time zone and without offset-from-UTC.
    "2017-01-23 12:34 PM" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd hh:mm a" )
)                                           // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object.
.atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )  // Assign time zone, to determine a moment. Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toInstant()                                // Adjusts from zone to UTC.
.toString()                                 // Generate string: 2017-01-23T17:34:00Z
.replace( "T" , " " )                       // Substitute SPACE for 'T' in middle.
.replace( "Z" , " Z" )                      // Insert SPACE before 'Z'.
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The other Answers use the troublesome old date-time classes (`Date`, `Calendar`, etc.), now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## `LocalDateTime`

> I have a string in the pattern yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a

Such an input string lacks any indication of offset-from-UTC or time zone. So we parse as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

Define a formatting pattern to match your input with a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) object.

```
String input = "2017-01-23 12:34 PM" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd hh:mm a" );
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> ldt.toString(): 2017-01-23T12:34

Note that a `LocalDateTime` is *not* a specific moment, only a vague idea about a range of possible moments. For example, a few minutes after midnight in Paris France is still “yesterday” in Montréal Canada. So without the context of a time zone such as [`Europe/Paris`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) or [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), just saying “a few minutes after midnight” has no meaning.

## `ZoneId`

> and i can get the time zone object separately in which the above string represents the date.

A time zone is represented by the [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) class.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

Apply the `ZoneId` to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) which is indeed a point on the timeline, a specific moment in history.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2017-01-23T12:34-05:00[America/Montreal]

## `Instant`

> I want to convert this to the below format. yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z

First, know that a `Z` literal character is short for `Zulu` and means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). In other words, an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero hours, `+00:00`.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

You can extract a `Instant` object from a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();  // Extracting the same moment but in UTC.
```

To generate a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, such as `2017-01-22T18:21:13.354Z`, call `toString`. The standard format has no spaces, uses a `T` to separate the year-month-date from the hour-minute-second, and appends the `Z` canonically for an offset of zero.

```
String output = instant.toString();
```

> instant.toString(): 2017-01-23T17:34:00Z

I strongly suggest using the standard formats whenever possible. If you insist on using spaces as in your stated desired format, either define your own formatting pattern in a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) object or just do a string manipulation on the output of [`Instant::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--).

```
String output = instant.toString()
                       .replace( "T" , " " )  // Substitute SPACE for T.
                       .replace( "Z" , " Z" ); // Insert SPACE before Z.
```

> output: 2017-01-23 17:34:00 Z

Try this [code live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/XE0kh6).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: The tldr is missing `.toInstant()`.

Comment: @Muhd Indeed. Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
String string1 = "2009-10-10 12:12:12 ";
SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z")
sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
Date date = sdf.parse(string1);
```

Comment: some times the getID() returns the string like this "America/Argentina/Ushuaia". So how can i use it

Comment: @Michael Konietzka  @shal I hurry i missed that, updated the answer

Comment: @Michael Konietzka You are right at your place, but its not the case

Answer (score 1):

Undoubtedly, the format which is generally used will be of a form `2014-10-05T15:23:01Z` (TZ)

For that one has to use this code

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
String dateInString = "2014-10-05T15:23:01Z";

 try {

     Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString.replaceAll("Z$", "+0000"));
     System.out.println(date);

 } catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Its output will be Sun Oct 05 20:53:01 IST 2014

However, I am not sure why we had to replaceAll "Z" if you do not add replaceAll the program will fail.

Comment: Just a note on the replaceAll() comment in your answer. replace() works with string literals where as replaceAll() or replaceFirst() supports a regular expression. If you did replace("Z", "+0000"), that should give you the same result as your replaceAll("Z$", "+0000")

Answer (score 0):

Create a new instance of [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) using your date pattern. Afterwards you can call it's parse method to convert date strings to a **java.util.Date** object.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this for the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z",
Eg: "2020-12-11 22:59:59 GMT", you can use different time zones like PST, GMT, etc.