# Format error with DateTime parser

Tags: java

I have this method:

```
public Date parseDate(String dateStr) {
      try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S z");
        return sdfSource.parse(dateStr);
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error occurred while parsing date: " + dateStr);
      }
    }
```

And my unit test as below:

```
public void testEDTDate() throws Exception {
      DateFormatConverter converter = new DateFormatConverter();
      Date date = converter.parseDate("2009-09-15 15:28:20.0 EDT");   
      System.out.println("Converted Date: " + date.toString());
  }
```

The output is:

```
Wed Sep 16 02:28:20 ICT 2009
```

This cause to the unit test fail. The expected result is:

```
Tue Sep 15 15:28:20.0 EDT 2009
```

The format of output also wrong when it missing the second. How should I fix to display the Date as expected?

Comment: Please check this..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203718/converting-string-to-date-with-timezone

Answer (score 3):

When you parse the `date` using a given format, you cannot expect `date.toString()` to return the same format - they're unrelated.

You will need to use [`DateFormat#format(Date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) in order to get a `String` in a given format, or you'll get whatever the system/implementation default is.

Comment: When I use DateFormat#format(Date) as you said but the result still the ICT timezone: 2009-09-16 02:28:20.0 ICT. I want to expect the result string as the given input

Comment: How about using `DateFormat#setTimeZone(TimeZone)`?