# Exception in parsing date format

Tags: java, date

I have a date in the following format

**//input date**

```
Thu Jun 06 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

**//output date format**

```
I want to change this to "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss".
```

I get the input date format from db. I have to change that into output date format which i will be showing it in a grid.

I tried the following code.

```
DateFormat outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"); 
                try
                {
                    Date date = outputDate.parse(facade.getDate.toString()); **//getting exception here**
                    outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss");
                    Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss").parse(outputDate
                            .format(date));
                    facade.setDate(date1);
                }catch (ParseException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I am getting

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-06-06 00:00:00.0".
```

Any help..

Comment: what line are you getting the error at?

Comment: In this line Date date = outputDate.parse(facade.getDate.toString());

Comment: For one thing, you want `dd-MM-yyyy, HH:mm:ss" as the output format. Read the docs for SimpleDateFormat. But you've got the same format everywhere - you're never specifying your *input* format. It's not entirely clear exactly what's in your input string. Does it actually contain the text "(India Standard Time)"? If so, you'll quite possibly need to remove that first.

Comment: yeah it contains the text India Standard Time. I am not sure about the input text format. so directly tried with the value.

Comment: Oh, and you need to consider which time zone you want to output the result in, too.

Comment: What kind of object is `facade.getDate`?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203718/converting-string-to-date-with-timezone it may be helpful to u

Comment: It sounds like you're currently just trying any number of things without really thinking it through logically. Take a step back, and start again. Read the docs for SimpleDateFormat. Work out your input format and output format.

Comment: Date object in Thu Jun 06 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) format.

Comment: If it is a `Date` object I don't see a reason to parse it - or maybe I missed something... :-)

Comment: What is facade? Is it already a date? If so, you don't need to parse it.
If its an object, see what format it is returning the date in? Its not matching your formatter..

Comment: I don't know what the input format is. Could someone help me to find it out ? I checked http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html. None of the time formats in the table seem to be matching with the one I am getting.

Comment: the facade.getDate returns a date only. I just want to format it to dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss

Comment: So if `facade.getDate` is already a `Date`, the line `Date date = outputDate.parse(facade.getDate.toString())` is not necessary. You convert the date to a `String` just in order to parse it to a date again. Just use `facade.getDate` as input for `outputDate.format()`.

Answer (score 1):

`"2013-06-06 00:00:00.0"` does not match `"dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"` your format should be `"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"` instead

But, looking at your code I'm guessing `facade.getDate` is actually a `java.sql.Timestamp` which inherits from `java.util.Date` so you can directly pass it to the format like so

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy, hh:mm:ss").format(facade.getDate)
```

Comment: That's not the format the OP really wants - it will use a 12 hour clock, and minutes instead of months.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for pointing that out...my bad for copy-pasting

Comment: The OP should consider locale and time zone too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code which works for me:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String input = "Thu Jun 06 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
        DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'z",
                                                      Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = inputFormat.parse(input);

        DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                                       Locale.ENGLISH);
        outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        String output = outputFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Things to consider:

- You need to work out your output time zone. Currently I've got it set to UTC, but that may not be what you want.
- You really need to take a step back and think things through. You've clearly got two different formats - you're trying to convert from one to the other. So creating three different `SimpleDateFormat` objects all with the *same* format is never going to work.
- You need to read documentation carefully... in `SimpleDateFormat`, `M` means month and `m` means minute; `h` uses the 12-hour clock and `H` uses the 24-hour clock.

This is assuming you actually *need* to start with a string though. If `getDate` is already a `Date` or a `Timestamp`, you can ignore the first part - just use the output part of the above code. You should avoid unnecessary string conversions wherever possible.

Note that `dd-MM-yyyy` is a *slightly* unusual format - are you sure you don't actually want `yyyy-MM-dd` which is more common (and sortable)?

Comment: I want to convert the string again to date format !!! Could you please help ?

Comment: @sahana: Why do you need to do that? Try to avoid string conversions as far as you can. If you *really* need to do this though, just use the same `SimpleDateFormat` but call `parse` instead of `format`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss");
try {
    Date date = outputDate.parse("2013-06-06 00:00:00.0");
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss").format(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

works well, line 1 was incorrect. Your SimpleDateFormat.parse needs to be in the exact format of the input date. Then you want to output it in a different format so you make another one and set the format then call SimpleDateFormat.format(date) and I put a println on it.

Answer (score 0):

Fault is here

```
DateFormat outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss");
```

pattern should be equals to `Thu Jun 06 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`. not to your out put strings pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void test() throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf_org = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date d = sdf_org.parse("Thu Jun 06 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf_target = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

    System.out.println(sdf_target.format(d));
}
```

output console : 2013-30-06 03:30:00.000

Comment: to convert back to date ??